# How to configure StrongLoop Heroku add-on for a LoopBack site?

Tags: heroku, loopbackjs, strongloop

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/strongloop/strongloop-buildpacks) for deploying a loopback app to Heroku, applying the buildpack as stated:

```
$ heroku apps:create --buildpack https://github.com/strongloop/strongloop-buildpacks.git
$ git push heroku master
```

The site runs on `$ heroku open`, but there is no StrongLoop add-on with the Strong Ops control panel. `$ heroku addons:open strongloop` message is  `!    Addon not installed: strongloop`

Is there a problem with the buildpack, or do I need to do something else to get the Strong Ops panel configured?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run

```
$heroku addons:add strongloop
```

Following that you should see Strongloop (StrongOps) add-on in your Resources tab on your Heroku dashboard. You can open it from there or you can open it from your terminal:

```
$heroku addons:open strongloop
```

Comment: At Aug 23, when you run heroku addons:add strongloop you get the following message: Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "strongloop", Also if you run: heroku addons:create strongloop the same message is given. It looks like there is no addon called loopback anymore?

Comment: I have the same issue "Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "strongloop".

Comment: Has anybody reached out to Strongloop to see the status of this addon? I imagine they are crazy busy at the moment refactoring for Node 4.0. Again, I can only speak to the success I had earlier in the year.

Comment: why does loopback need an addon for heroku, I though it was just node code underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
$ heroku addons:add strongloop
```

Comment: This answer has come for review as low-quality. While I will not recommend deletion, I would strongly recommend that you improve the answer by explaining what the above command does and how it will help solve the question.